# How can I create ExpansionPanelList from model from API on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to create on flutter a dynamic ExpansionPanelList which each ExpansionPanel is provided by my API REST service.

I have connected my API with my app and I can list all the **Products**:

ProductosProvider:

```
List<ProductoModel> _productos = new List();
final _productosStreamController = StreamController<List<ProductoModel>>.broadcast();
Function(List<ProductoModel>) get productosSink => _productosStreamController.sink.add;
Stream<List<ProductoModel>> get productosStream => _productosStreamController.stream;
```

List products method:

```
Future<ProductList> listaProductos() async {
    // Call API
    final resp = await http.get(_url);
    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    final productos = new ProductList.fromJsonList( decodedData );
    _productos.addAll(productos.items);
    productosSink( _productos );
    return productos;
  }
```

So, calling this **listaProductos** method I can list all the products from the remote database.

On my **Widget** page:

```
class _CartaPageState extends State<CartaPage> {
  // Create provider
  ProductosProvider productosProvider;
...
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Initialize provider
    productosProvider = new ProductosProvider();
    // Listen data
    final productos = productosProvider.listaProductos();
  );
```

Here is where I have the issues, I would like to create the **ExpansionPanelList** using a **StreamBuilder**

```
Widget _listaProductos( Buildcontext context ) {
return StreamBuilder(
      // Suscribe to stream
      stream: productosProvider.productosStream,
      builder: ( context , AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductoModel>> snapshot) {
        if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
          final productos = snapshot.data ?? [];
          // Creamos la lista de items
          // This method transform Producto List to Item List
          productosItems = productosProvider.productosToList();
          return ExpansionPanelList(
            animationDuration: Duration( milliseconds: 500 ),
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                productosItems[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
              });
            },
            children: productosItems.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
              return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.headerValue),
                  );
                },
                body: ListTile(
                  title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                ),
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
              );
            }).toList()
            ...
}
```

On this way, my productosItem is refreshing all the time and the state is not updated, so the ExpansionPanel is never open/collapsed.

I don't know if I am declaring the provider on the right place, if the productosToList must be out of the provider...

Thank you in advance